# Dapper One-To-Many with multiple tables

Tags: .net, dapper

I have Dapper retrieving my data like this:

```
using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    const string sql =
                "SELECT Offers.*, " +
                "       OfferDetails.*," +
                "       SomeLookup.Id AS SomeLookupId, SomeLookup.* " +
                "FROM   Offers " +
                "INNER JOIN OfferBets ON Offers.Id = OfferBets.OfferId " +
                "INNER JOIN SomeLookup ON SomeLookup.Id = Offers.SomeLookupId";

   dbConnection.Open();

   var betDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Offer>();

   return await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Offer, OfferBet, SomeLookup, Offer>(
                sql,
                (offer, bet, someLookup) =>
                {
                    if (!betDictionary.TryGetValue(offer.Id, out var offerEntry))
                    {
                        offerEntry = offer;
                        offerEntry.SomeLookup = someLookup;
                        offerEntry.Bets = new List<OfferBet>();
                        betDictionary.Add(offer.Id, offerEntry);
                    }

                    offerEntry.Bets.Add(bet);

                    return offerEntry;
                },
                splitOn: "OfferId, SomeLookupId"
            );
    }
}
```

It should return a list of Offers which each contain a list of OfferDetails and one SomeLookup.

What I get is a list of orders for each OrderDetails object. It is returning the joined dataset and populating an Order for each record (and each has 1 OrderDetails item in the collection).

What have I done wrong in the duplicate detection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer here was to alias the ID field of OfferDetails and then split on that, so the SQL looks like

```
SELECT Offers.*,
       OfferDetails.Id AS OfferDetailId, OfferDetails.*,
       SomeLookup.Id AS SomeLookupId, SomeLookup.*
FROM   Offers
INNER JOIN OfferDetails ON Offers.Id = OfferDetails.OfferId
INNER JOIN SomeLookup ON SomeLookup.Id = Offers.SomeLookupId"
```

Then the splitOn part looks like

```
splitOn: "OfferBetId, SomeLookupId",
```

This leaves duplicates in the `Offers` so we also need to do `.Distinct()` on the result.

Answer (score 4):

I assume *OfferDetails / OfferBets* also contains a column called *Id* in addtion to *OfferId* and this column is placed before *OfferId* and this gets mixed up. So if you change the *splitOn* parameter to *splitOn: "Id, SomeLookupId"* it might work.

```
[Test]
public void tstAbc()
{
    using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        const string sql = @"WITH Offers AS (

                                 SELECT * FROM (
                                     VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2)
                                     ) AS a (Id, SomeLookupId)
                             ),

                             OfferBets AS (

                                 SELECT * FROM (
                                     VALUES
                                         (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3)
                                     ) AS a (Id, OfferId)

                             ),

                             SomeLookup AS (

                                 SELECT * FROM (
                                     VALUES
                                         (1), (2), (3)
                                     ) AS a (Id)

                             )

                             SELECT Offers.*,
                                    OfferBets.*,
                                    SomeLookup.Id AS SomeLookupId, SomeLookup.*
                             FROM   Offers
                             INNER JOIN OfferBets ON Offers.Id = OfferBets.OfferId
                             INNER JOIN SomeLookup ON SomeLookup.Id = Offers.SomeLookupId";

        dbConnection.Open();

        var betDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Offer>();

        var res = dbConnection.Query<Offer, OfferBet, SomeLookup, Offer>(
            sql,
            (offer, bet, someLookup) =>
            {
                if (!betDictionary.TryGetValue(offer.Id, out var offerEntry))
                {
                    offerEntry = offer;
                    offerEntry.Bets = new List<OfferBet>();
                    betDictionary.Add(offer.Id, offerEntry);
                }

                offerEntry.Bets.Add(bet);
                offerEntry.SomeLookup = someLookup;

                return offerEntry;
            },
            splitOn: "Id, SomeLookupId"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice spot on the OfferBet.Id field, by simply adding `OfferBets.Id As OfferBetId` before `OfferBets.*` then splitting on that, I now get all the correct bets inside the offer object.